# NPSP Data Import Error: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Account.BillingCity

Tags: npsp

I was trying to use the NPSP Data Import Wizard. I loaded all o f the files, but then when I tried to import the files, I got a lot errors. The error was:

> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested
>   field: Account.BillingCity

However I looked at some of the error records and they are not any different from the ones that imported correctly. I have no idea how to fix this so that I can import the data. I am on the Nonprofit Success Pack version 3.114

I'm using the Household Account model.  Can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: BTW - the [Power of Us Hub](powerofus.force.com) is the best place to find answers on NPSP-specific questions and also participate with the rest of the NPSP community..  You can login with your Salesforce ID to get access.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue that has been fixed and will be pushed to sandboxes tomorrow, and to production instances next week.

https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/issues/2859